# Fragment, Null pointer Exception in searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am creating a fragment list with a search facility. I am trying to port the code from ActionBarSherlock to appcompat. Made most of the changes required. I am getting a null pointer exception error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.rand.LatestFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(LatestFragment.java:266)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1582)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1967)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:146)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:293)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**LatestFragment.java**

```
public class LatestFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lsv_latest;
    List<ItemLatest> arrayOfLatestMusic;
    LatestGridAdapter objAdapter;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    ArrayList<String> allListImageUrl,allListMusicCatName,allListMusicShare;
    ArrayList<String> allListMusicId,allListMusicCatId,allListMusicUrl,allListMusicName,allListMusicDuration,allListMusicDesc;
    String[] allArrayImage,allArrayMusicCatName,allArrayMusicShare;
    String[] allArrayMusicId,allArrayMusicCatId,allArrayMusicurl,allArrayMusicName,allArrayMusicDuration,allArrayMusicDesc;
    private ItemLatest objAllBean;
    private int columnWidth;
    JsonUtils util;
    int textlength = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        lsv_latest=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lsv_latest);
        arrayOfLatestMusic=new ArrayList<ItemLatest>();
        allListImageUrl=new ArrayList<String>();
        allListMusicCatName=new ArrayList<String>();
        allListMusicCatId=new ArrayList<String>();
        allListMusicId=new ArrayList<String>();
        allListMusicName=new ArrayList<String>();
        allListMusicUrl=new ArrayList<String>();
        allListMusicDuration=new ArrayList<String>();
        allListMusicDesc=new ArrayList<String>();
        allListMusicShare=new ArrayList<String>();

        allArrayImage=new String[allListImageUrl.size()];
        allArrayMusicCatName=new String[allListMusicCatName.size()];
        allArrayMusicId=new String[allListMusicId.size()];
        allArrayMusicCatId=new String[allListMusicCatId.size()];
        allArrayMusicurl=new String[allListMusicUrl.size()];
        allArrayMusicName=new String[allListMusicName.size()];
        allArrayMusicDuration=new String[allListMusicDuration.size()];
        allArrayMusicDesc=new String[allListMusicDesc.size()];
        allArrayMusicShare=new String[allListMusicShare.size()];

        util=new JsonUtils(getActivity());


        if (JsonUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
            new MyTask().execute(Constant.LATEST_URL);
        } else {
            showToast("No Network Connection!!!");
             alert.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        }


        lsv_latest.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                objAllBean=arrayOfLatestMusic.get(position);
                int pos=objAllBean.getId();


                Constant.MUSIC_ID=String.valueOf(pos);
                Constant.MUSIC_PLAY_ID=""; 

                Log.e("Music_id", Constant.MUSIC_ID);
                Intent intplay=new Intent(getActivity(),SongPlay1.class);
                intplay.putExtra("POSITION", pos);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_IMAGE", allArrayImage);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_CATNAME", allArrayMusicCatName);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_CATID", allArrayMusicCatId);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_URL", allArrayMusicurl);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_NAME", allArrayMusicName);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_CID", allArrayMusicId);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_DURATION", allArrayMusicDuration);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_DISCRIPTION", allArrayMusicDesc);
                intplay.putExtra("MP3_SHARE", allArrayMusicShare);

            startActivity(intplay);



            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }




    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return JsonUtils.getJSONString(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (null != pDialog && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (null == result || result.length() == 0) {
                showToast("Server Connection Error");
                alert.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Server Connection Error",
                        "May Server Under Maintainance Or Low Network", false);

            } else {

                try {
                    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(Constant.LATEST_ARRAY_NAME);
                    JSONObject objJson = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                          objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        ItemLatest objItem = new ItemLatest();

                        objItem.setId(objJson.getInt(Constant.LATEST_ID));
                        objItem.setCategoryId(objJson.getInt(Constant.LATEST_CATID));
                        objItem.setCategoryName(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_CAT_NAME));
                        objItem.setMp3Name(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_MP3_NAME));
                        objItem.setMp3Url(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_MP3_URL));
                        objItem.setShareUrl(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_MP3_SHARE_URL));
                        objItem.setDescription(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_MP3_DESCRIPTION));
                        objItem.setDuration(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_MP3_DURATION));
                        objItem.setImage(objJson.getString(Constant.LATEST_MP3_IMAGE_THUMB));

                        arrayOfLatestMusic.add(objItem);


                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for(int j=0;j<arrayOfLatestMusic.size();j++)
                {

                    objAllBean=arrayOfLatestMusic.get(j);

                    allListImageUrl.add(objAllBean.getImage());
                    allArrayImage=allListImageUrl.toArray(allArrayImage);

                    allListMusicCatName.add(objAllBean.getCategoryName());
                    allArrayMusicCatName=allListMusicCatName.toArray(allArrayMusicCatName);

                    allListMusicId.add(String.valueOf(objAllBean.getId()));
                    allArrayMusicId=allListMusicId.toArray(allArrayMusicId);

                    allListMusicCatId.add(String.valueOf(objAllBean.getCategoryId()));
                    allArrayMusicCatId=allListMusicCatId.toArray(allArrayMusicCatId);


                    allListMusicUrl.add(String.valueOf(objAllBean.getMp3Url()));
                    allArrayMusicurl=allListMusicUrl.toArray(allArrayMusicurl);

                    allListMusicName.add(String.valueOf(objAllBean.getMp3Name()));
                    allArrayMusicName=allListMusicName.toArray(allArrayMusicName);

                    allListMusicDuration.add(String.valueOf(objAllBean.getDuration()));
                    allArrayMusicDuration=allListMusicDuration.toArray(allArrayMusicDuration);

                    allListMusicDesc.add(objAllBean.getDescription());
                    allArrayMusicDesc=allListMusicDesc.toArray(allArrayMusicDesc);

                    allListMusicShare.add(objAllBean.getShareUrl());
                    allArrayMusicShare=allListMusicShare.toArray(allArrayMusicShare);

                }

            setAdapterToListview();
        }

        }
    }



    public void setAdapterToListview() {
        objAdapter = new LatestGridAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.latest_lsv_item,
                arrayOfLatestMusic,columnWidth);
        lsv_latest.setAdapter(objAdapter);
    }

    public void showToast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        //MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        //   final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(R.id.search);
        //   final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();


        //  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
                    searchView.setQuery(" ", false);
                }
            }
        });


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                textlength = newText.length();
                arrayOfLatestMusic.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < allArrayMusicName.length; i++) {
                    if (textlength <= allArrayMusicName[i].length()) {
                        if (newText.toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) allArrayMusicName[i].subSequence(0, textlength))) {


                            ItemLatest objItem = new ItemLatest();

                            objItem.setId(Integer.parseInt(allArrayMusicId[i]));
                            objItem.setCategoryId(Integer.parseInt(allArrayMusicCatId[i]));
                            objItem.setCategoryName(allArrayMusicCatName[i]);
                            objItem.setDescription(allArrayMusicDesc[i]);
                            objItem.setDuration(allArrayMusicDuration[i]);
                            objItem.setImage(allArrayImage[i]);
                            objItem.setMp3Name(allArrayMusicName[i]);
                            objItem.setMp3Url(allArrayMusicurl[i]);
                            objItem.setShareUrl(allArrayMusicShare[i]);

                            arrayOfLatestMusic.add(objItem);

                        }
                    }
                }

                setAdapterToListview();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Do something
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**menu_search.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">    
 <item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/menu_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/search"
      app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" 
      android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**fragment_latest.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f8f8f8"
android:id="@+id/rootlayout"
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner">
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lsv_latest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@color/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please specify the line of error? What is line 266?

Comment: are you getting error when click the searchview button or compile time itself ??

Comment: the error happens in this line  of  LatestFragment.java
        searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()

Comment: I am getting this error in run-time. when I click the tab for this fragment.